# How to extend root partition on remote virtual machines?

Tags: linux, partition

[image: Snapshot of VM disk partitions]

Here is what happend in the last week:

1. I created a Suse12 virtual machine in VMWare on my Windows 10.
2. I exported the VM as an OVF file and gave it to someone else to deploy it on some remote server; and "someone" has given it a 1TB disk space.
3. I ssh-connected to the remote VM, and found the root partition is only 19G, which comes from my VMWare configuration apparently and is far from enough for the related work, while there are like 980GB of disk out there free of use.

So my question is, how can I extend the root volume to 700GB when I can only connect to the server by ssh?

Edit: I have solved the problem following instructions here -> https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7018329
It turns out the file system **btrfs** matters a lot. I'd been following wrong instructions not realizing the difference between file systems.

Comment: Add your filesystem to the question please. ext4?

Comment: It's btrfs. --so no wonder I've tried several instructions and none of them worked, didn't realize the filesystem matters....

Comment: Growing / is a PITA. Booting from rescue disk, deleting and recreating sda2, and then `btrfs filesystem resize max /`

Comment: Yes exactly. You've enlightened me dear sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try - https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7018329

Hopefully this works out for you.

Also, make sure you're using SLES 12 SP3, SP2 and prior are already on LTSS.

Comment: Ahh, I see you used this link to fix it. Good! Sorry I didn't notice before :)